# Downspouts smaller than 2x3?

Tags: gutters

I have an old metal overhang from when my home was built back in the 60's. It has in integrated gutter and currently no downspouts to direct the water. I went to Lowes and purchased the smaller downspouts they had (2x3) and they seem to be too big.

[image]
[image]
[image]

My question is do they make gutters that are smaller than 2x3? Or am i missing something here? Thank you

Comment: I've never seen one like that but how about just cutting the opening larger?

Comment: The problem is that the opening I would have to cut is too large for the gutter to install the adapter.

Comment: take those photos to a local plumbing supplies place, they may well know what used to be in that unpainted part.

Comment: Yes you have a old odd set up. And finding parts is not going to be easy,for a down spot. Could treat it as a drain and use drain parts. Two inch or less and paint it to finish it off.

Comment: Did it at my house , needed bigger down spots to let water out faster.  Works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get custom made downspouts and outlets at a sheet metal shop if you want.

What you have there is not a problem and if you have access from the top (which is where you need to install the outlet, from inside the gutter - its dark so I can't tell), you can easily modify that outlet so the flanges fit inside the gutter.

Answer (score 0):

The smaller hole won’t be a problem on some homes this is done to reduce leaves from getting into the downspouts, I thought the undersized holes were strange on my last home that I had copper gutter installed and they used small holes and said this was to prevent leaves from getting in as easily and plugging the down spouts and lines to the holding cistern’s we used for watering.